# URL in address bar does not get the redirections

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, subdomain, url, redirection

after deploying this website I was developing locally, on a Windows Server 2008 R2, I cannot seem to get the updated URLs from the server on my browser.

The scenario is like this:

I have a main domain which is directing to a live website. I have created a subdomain like: beta.domain.com to redirect to the public IP of the IIS server.

The problem is, the browser address bar does not get updated when I navigate through my website. I have a few redirections to external websites which they also do not work because of this.

I have also noticed, in my browser's status bar, my website public address is shown instead of the domain when I hover over a link on the page.

I do not think problem is with IIS because when I browse the website using http:/localhost/ on the server, it works perfectly.

I do not have any URL Rewrite rules or permanent redirections enabled.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description It sounds like your "redirect" is actually a framed forwarder. 
Essentially an iframe hosted at your domain host which is then in turn loading your website in to the iframe via the ip address.

To properly deploy the site, you will need to alter you domain so that the A record is set to the ip your web server and not the ip of your domain providers forwarding server.

Comment: yes. correct I deleted the forwarder record and added an A Record and it works now. Thanks